# ZeroMQ retransmitting pub-sub model

Tags: node.js, typescript, zeromq

I'm trying to use the ZeroMQ javascript bindings to implement a re-transmitting pub-sub backbone.

Something to the effect of:

- inbound modules announce themselves to the backbone, the backbone subscribes to them and re-transmits on its own publisher socket
- outbound modules subscribe to backbone

I'm running into an issue with the pub sockets required to be used from a single thread though.

My current code, was something like this:

```
async function listen(name: string, sub: zmq.Subscriber, pub: zmq.Publisher) {
    let id = 0;
    for await (const [topic, msg] of sub) {
        console.log(`BACKBONE | ${name} | received a message id: ${++id} related to: ${topic.toString()} containing message: ${msg.toString()}`);
        await pub.send([topic, msg]);
    }
}
```

Which gets instantiated for each of the inbound modules, but then of course they clash on `pub.send`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a queue to serialize the socket access, which resolved the problem.

```
import * as zmq from "zeromq"

export class PublisherQueue {
    private queue: Buffer[][] = []
    constructor(private publisher: zmq.Publisher) { }

    private static toBuffer(value: Buffer | string): Buffer {
        if (value instanceof Buffer) {
            return value as Buffer;
        } else {
            return Buffer.from(value as string);
        }
    }

    send(topic: Buffer | string, msg: Buffer | string) {
        this.queue.push([PublisherQueue.toBuffer(topic), PublisherQueue.toBuffer(msg)]);
    }

    async run() {
        while (true) {
            if (this.queue.length > 0) {
                let msg = this.queue.shift();
                if (msg !== undefined) {
                    await this.publisher.send(msg);
                }
            } else {
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 50));
            }
        }
    }
}
```